# Approximate computation of a linear function

Tags: sampling, simulation, linear, approximation

I am not sure that this is the right stackexchange site for this, but here goes:

Let $d_1,\ldots,d_n$ be known real numbers, some positive, some negative. Let $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ be non-negative numbers whose sum is 1, (i.e., $v_i\ge 0, \sum_i v_i = 1$).

My goal is to evaluate if their dot product is positive:
$$
S = \sum_{i=1}^{n}{d_i v_i} > 0
$$

The number $d_i$ are given to us in advance; however, the numbers $v_i$ are not given to us, and evaluating each one is expensive. Is there a way to test $S > 0$ with less than the $n$ evaluations, with high probability? If so, what is the required number of evaluations to achieve a required certainty?

My initial thoughts were along the lines of: Draw $k$ subsets of $t$ $v$-s, evaluate the sum on the subset, and decide the total sum is positive if the majority of the $k$ sum over subsets were positive. However, from simulations, I could not find $k,t$ for a significant saving.

Comment: Obviously it can be done in $n-1$ evaluations due to the sum-to-unity constraint.  This suggests drawing the $v_i$ in the same order as the descending sequence of $|d_i|$, stopping at any point the sign of $S$ is definite. If you want to do any better, what can you tell us about the distribution of the $v_i$?

Comment: This kind of set up is typical in financial portfolio management, $v_i$ would weights of assets, and the short positions are not allowed so they're all nonnegative. $S_i$ would be returns on assets, and $S$ is a return of portfolio

Comment: The actual setting is that each $v_i \sim \chi^2$, but their sum is known.

Comment: It is not possible for *any* of the $v_i$ to have a $\chi^2$ distribution if they are going to sum to unity!

Comment: If you want to add the assumption about their distribution, replace the sum of unity with having the sum known, but not necessarily unity.